# Avoid that Powershell autocomplete the path

Tags: powershell

I want to use a Linux path in a Powershell script. I want to write sth in a file with this Command:

```
Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Command "echo ""$LogFileContent"" > '/vol/Systemcheck/nsclient_ini_Update/Log_nsclient_ini.html'
```

But I got an error where he said that he can't find the path `C:/vol/Systemcheck/nsclient_ini_Update/Log_nsclient_ini.html` How can I avoid that PS autocomplete the `C:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file redirection is *outside* the command you want to run on the remote machine. Therefore, you get PowerShell's interpretation of the path. You are giving an *absolute* path here (as indicated by the leading `/` or `\`) which results in referring to the root directory of the current volume on Windows. If your current working directory is somewhere on `C:`, then that's what you get.

This may be because you're missing the closing `"` at the end of the command line. But truth to be told, I think in that case PowerShell would normally just error out with a parsing error.